# Issues with GRUB and Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently upgrade my 60GB SSD to a 500GB SSD. I installed Windows 8.1 clean on the SSD and everything was fine and dandy. Then for fun, since I am a huge fan of Ubuntu (currently installed on my laptop), I thought I would plug my old 60GB SSD into my hot swap bay and install Ubuntu 14.04 on it. That went well to and I was super happy! However, when I installed Ubuntu on the 60GB SSD it also installed grub onto it instead of onto the new 500GB SSD with windows on it. So now I can not boot into Windows or Ubuntu (obviously) when the 60GB SSD is removed.

Both operating systems function perfectly when the 60GB SSD is installed so this isn't a huge issue. Just very annoying. I tried moving grub to the new 500GB SSD (using sudo install-grub /dev/sda) so that windows can run even when the 60GB SSD with Ubuntu is not connected however I was unable to get it to work. When ever the 60GB SSD is removed it shows the grub rescue screen.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can remove grub from the old SSD and move it to the new one?

I am currently thinking that I should reinstall Ubuntu using a live USB and specify /dev/sda as the location of the boot loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with Something Else manual install option do you get the choice on which drive to install boot loader into. So with multiple drives you always use Something Else.

You can use Boot-Repair's advanced options and choose an operating system and which drive to install its boot loader into. Or Windows into Windows drive and grub into Ubuntu drive. Or you can use Windows repair flash drive to repair Windows and when in Ubuntu install grub to sdb.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You did not want grub in sda, it that is 500GB drive but sdb the 60GB drive and only in the 60GB drive.

reinstall from working (not liveCD/DVD/USB) system - first find Ubuntu drive (example is drive sdb but use your drive not partitions):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

if it's "/dev/sdb"  then just run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

If that returns any errors run:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
sudo update-grub
```

How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: I used boot repair to restore a generic MBR on sda and then installed grub on sde and now everything is working very well! Thanks for your help